# Как получить значение с api другого сайта?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как получить на своем сайте значение курса биткоина с этого сайта https://coinmarketcap.com/

Сделал на сайте у себя так, но ничего не выводит:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var xhre = new XMLHttpRequest();
var elm = document.getElementById("data-bt");
var bitdata;
var etherdata;
xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1/?convert=USD', false);

xhr.send();

if (xhr.status != 200) {
  console.log( xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText );
} else {
  bitdata = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
  elm.innerHTML = bitdata.data.quotes.USD.price;
  alert(bitdata.data.quotes.USD.price);
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>курс = <span id="data-bt"></span></div>
```

---

сделал на сайте у себя так, но ничего не выводит

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var xhre = new XMLHttpRequest();
var elm = document.getElementById("data-bt");
var bitdata;
var etherdata;
xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1/?convert=USD', false);

xhr.send();

if (xhr.status != 200) {
  console.log( xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText );
} else {
  bitdata = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
  elm.innerHTML = bitdata.data.quotes.USD.price;
  alert(bitdata.data.quotes.USD.price);
}
});
```

Comment: Для этого есть специальные IP

Comment: не подскажите как сделать?

Comment: yfb「cfqんtvj；yjyfqんbあぴ

Comment: Тьфу, раскладка. На их сайте можно найти api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С помощью API описанное на их сайте https://coinmarketcap.com/ru/api/

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var elm = document.getElementById("btc");
var bitdata;
xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1/?convert=USD', false);

xhr.send();

if (xhr.status != 200) {
  console.log( xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText );
} else {
  bitdata = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
  elm.innerHTML = bitdata.data.quotes.USD.price;
}
```

```html
Курс Bitcoin <span id=btc>NULL</span>＄
```

Или "живой курс"　Через long poll

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var elm = document.getElementById("btc");
var bitdata;


setInterval(function(){
xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1/?convert=USD', false);
  xhr.send();

  if (xhr.status != 200) {
    console.log( xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText );
  } else {
    bitdata = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    elm.innerHTML = bitdata.data.quotes.USD.price;
  }
},1000);
```

```html
Курс Bitcoin <span id=btc>NULL</span>＄
```

Comment: спасибо, уже разобрался